# How to fall back to the default Color Theme in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, themes

I have applied a [Color Theme](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme). How can I get back to the default theme without restarting Emacs (version 23)?

Comment: Please give more details. What version of Emacs are you running? How did you change the colors (there's more than one way)?

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
M-x color-theme-select
```

Move point (the cursor) to first line showing:

```
[Reset]
```

and press 'Enter' (return).

Alternatively, to get back to the *Emacs* default themes, also try:

```
M-x color-theme-emacs-21
```

or

```
M-x color-theme-standard
```

However, from your question it's not clear which theme you initially started with.  For example, if you simply been using the default theme provided in the [color-theme quickstart](http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/#sec8) when you first (manually) installed color-theme then do this:

```
M-x color-theme-hober
```

or whatever you had specified in your .emacs file (if applicable).

Answer (score 1):

That's a tricky one. What I have done before is make a color theme from your default ( there's a library out there that does it but the name escapes me (color-theme-maker) maybe?)

Then you can always switch back to it whenever you want. That's what I did, I named it default-23 or something. Good luck.